# Image filling a button UWP Xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am having problem in stretching my image to fill the button,I am new in UWP this is my code:

```
 <Grid  Margin="0,0,0,54" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="39" Style="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, ElementName=grid}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"  Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Image Source="images/icon1.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="True" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" />

        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1"  Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Image Source="images/icon2.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="True" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" />
        </Button>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Without further details about what you currently get and what you want to have, we cannot help you...

Comment: thanks Sibbl for your reply,with this code my image doesn't fill the button,it is in the center of the button :)

Comment: Replaced your image source with my own image, your code worked more than fine.

Comment: sorry I am new in this forum I can't put images :(

Comment: ok thanks pand for your reply so I should change the image to fit the button width and heigth?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably need to change the Padding and BorderThickness properties of the button. As code below :

```
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
        <Image Source="Assets/microsoft.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Source="/Assets/microsoft.png" will work even if the Xaml file is not in the root folder.